# UIButton size not updating automatically after updating button image, using autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a UIButton which is constrained with leading, trailing and center vertically constraints.  The label on the left of the button grows until the trailing constraint of the button (greater than constraint) reaches the limit at which point the button does not move any closer to the switch and the label text begins to truncate.

[image]

There is a case where the button is set to hidden.  This creates an extra gap between the label and switch when there is long text in the label.  I am setting the image of the button to nil and expect it to resize based on the constraints but it never does.

[image]

Here is the code that attempts to force the resizing:

```
func hideInfoButon(hide: Bool) {
    infoButton.hidden = hide
    if hide {
        infoButton.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
    } else {
        infoButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icn_info_gry"), forState: .Normal)
    }

    setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    setNeedsLayout()
}
```

I have confirmed that the hide method is properly called and the image is actually being set to nil.  I confirmed by not hiding the button and giving it a background color to make it visible.

Is there a solution which does not require me to add a width constraint to the button?

The content is in a tableViewCell for reference.

Comment: What about setting the button's width to zero? Would that be a possible solution?

Comment: UIStackView is good solution for this case, if deployment target in your project >= ios 9.0

Answer (score 0):

**1. Add Constraints to label**

[image]

**2. Add Constraints to Info Button**

[image]

**3. Info Button trailing space must be standard spacing**

[image]

**4. Create Info Button Width IBOutlet Like**

[image]

**5. And when you wnat to hide button set width constraints 0**

```
infoButtonWidth.constant=0
```

Answer (score -1):

A hidden button will still occupy space. You could alternatively remove the button rather than hiding it...

```
infoButton.removeFromSuperview()
```

If you do this, you will probably also need an extra constraint between the label and the switch for when the button is removed. This constraint should have a lower priority so that it does not conflict when the button is visible.

EDIT:

Thinking about it further, this may cause headaches when cells are reused between rows. You may find it easier to have an IBOutlet for the button's width constraint, and just set it to zero to hide.

Comment: I would expect the button size to change if the content in the button changes and the proper constraints are setup.  Same as changing the text of a label.